# It's possibille for a dll file to remember a value?

Tags: dll

I have this code:

```
static int nr = 0;

public static void MyMethod() {
if (nr == 0) nr = 1;
}
```

I build the project and I get the dll file. I use the dll file for the first time and I know for sure that the nr is 0 and nr will get the "1" value. I destroy the AppDomain and I loose that value.

My question: I have the dll file.
I use the dll file for the first time and my code generate a value.
Can I maintain that value or any value in my code without coding it or without saving in a file or in a registry?

Answer (score 0):

if u want to maintain that value only on that particular page then store in a global variable or in ViewState intrinsic object. For User level store in Session.